# Printing picture on a canvas

Tags: photo-editing, printing, resolution, dpi, canvas

I am trying to print a picture on a canvas, I would like the canvas to be 16x24 in size. I was told that my picture is 75 DPI, is the resolution good enough for the canvas to be nice and clear?

Comment: 16x24 millimeters, meters, inches, miles? And what are the dimensions of your image (in pixels)

Answer (score 0):

How the final print looks depends on making sure you have enough image resolution to support the physical dimensions of the image. If you have too few pixels, they will be stretched in the final print, and look blocky and out of focus.

To determine, look in the 'Get Info' on Mac or Properties in Windows for the image file, and it will list the pixel dimensions. You then need to find the reference from your printer service to see what they recommend. For example, here is what Mpix.com, a USA national photo print service recommends:

In your case the dimensions needed for a 16x24 image are 4000x6000 or as low as 1600x2400.

https://www.mpix.com/help/uploading-photos

[image]

Comment: Are those recommendations for canvas or for photo paper?

Comment: Non-specific @MichaelC, MPix.com only specifies these as being recommended for 'a premium quality print'. Their canvas print ordering page offers no other recommendations

Comment: That's surprising. I use Mpix (or Miller's, which is the same company) for most of my printing needs. I've always been happy with their product (at least when I've sent them a good file, LOL). Canvas is a significantly lower resolution medium than photo paper, I would have expected them to have had separate recommendations in terms of ppi.